# QGIS to tilemill export

Tags: qgis, mapbox, tilemill, mapnik

does anyone know if there is a way to save a QGIS project in a manner that allows it or if there is a way to save a qgis project as mbtiles for use with mapbox

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].